# Tortoise SVN attempt to write a readonly database windows

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Currently getting an error when trying to commit code via Tortoise SVN.

```
Transmitting file data ..done
Committing transaction... Committed revision 2827.
Warning: post commit FS processing had error: 
sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
```

There are no locks which I can see, Any recommendations to solutions will be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error in your particular case happens on the server side. There is a problem with the post-commit hook script. Contact the server or repository admin.

---

Check the permissions to the working copy. If the error is produced by a server side hook script, contact the server administrator.

I guess that the complete error message that you receive looks like in this example:

```
svn: E155004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155004: Failed to lock working copy 'C:\Users\usr\myproject'.
svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
svn: E200042: Additional errors:
svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
```

This issue should be caused by insufficient permissions to `.svn` directory and  `.svn/wc.db` file in particular (e.g. `C:\Users\usr\myproject\.svn\wc.db`). You should double-check that the user account that runs `svn commit` has permissions to write to C:\Users\usr\myproject\ directory and its contents.

You can also workaround this issue by [checking out a fresh working copy](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/initial/) to a new location where you have the required permissions.

Comment: I have tried checking out a fresh copy but still face the same error.

`Transmitting file data ..done
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 2827.

Warning: post commit FS processing had error:
sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database`

Comment: @TahirMehmet contact the admin, the problem is on the server side

Comment: I got this error when logged in to Linux as the wrong user. Once I did a sudo to log in as the user profile that had svn permissions, I was able to work away OK.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when logged in to Linux as the wrong user. Once I did a "sudo su -" to log in as the user profile that had svn permissions, I was able to work away OK.